# dictionary binding two different list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a=[2,1]
b=['app','applied']
f={}
for id in a:
   for name in b:

     f[id]=name
```

the output is `{2:'app', 1: 'app'}`
after i generated another for loop

```
for c in f:
   print(c)
```

Then output is 2,1 not show value
    and I tried

```
for c,k in f:
   print(c,k)

return error
```

But i need both key and value
    Please help me

I Tried many time cannot get solution. I bind two different list in dictionary but get only key value but value should only one value to bind in key. Please help me

Comment: How is this related to django? What's the expected output?

Comment: Try: `for c,k in f.items()`. Iterating `f` iterates keys, not items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it [functions zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
a = [2, 1]
b = ['app', 'applied']
f = dict(zip(a,b))
print(f.items())
```

Comment: Thank u very much

Comment: glad to help you